# k-means clustering-- why all same clusters?

Tags: r, k-means

I am running a k-means clustering on a set of text data with 10842 number of tweets. I set the k to be 5 and I got my clusters as per below

cluster1:booking flight NA

cluster2:flight booking NA

cluster3:flight booking NA

cluster4:flight booking NA

cluster5:booking flight NA

***I do not understand why all the clusters are same??***

```
myCorpus<-Corpus(VectorSource(myCorpus$text))
myCorpusCopy<-myCorpus
myCorpus<-tm_map(myCorpus,stemDocument)
myCorpus<-tm_map(myCorpus,stemCompletion,dictionary=myCorpusCopy)
myTdm<-TermDocumentMatrix(myCorpus,control=list(wordLengths=c(1,Inf)))
myTdm2<-removeSparseTerms(myTdm,sparse=0.95)
m2<-as.matrix(myTdm2)
m3<-t(m2)
set.seed(122)
k<-5
kmeansResult<-kmeans(m3,k)
round(kmeansResult$centers,digits=3)

for(i in 1:k){
cat(paste("cluster",i,":",sep=""))
s<-sort(kmeansResult$centers[i,],decreasing=T)
cat(names(s)[1:3],"\n")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that k-means clustering requires you to specify the number of clusters in advance (in contrast to, say, hierarchical clustering). Without having access to your data set (and thus being unable to reproduce what you've presented here), the most obvious reason that you're obtaining seemingly homogeneous clusters is that there's a problem with the number of clusters you're specifying beforehand.

The most immediate solution is to try out the `NbClust` package in R to determine the number of clusters appropriate for your data.

Here's a sample code using a toy data set to give you an idea of how to proceed:

```
# install.packages("NbClust")
library(NbClust)
set.seed(1234)
df <- rbind(matrix(rnorm(100,sd=0.1),ncol=2),
     matrix(rnorm(100,mean=1,sd=0.2),ncol=2),
     matrix(rnorm(100,mean=5,sd=0.1),ncol=2),
     matrix(rnorm(100,mean=7,sd=0.2),ncol=2))

# "scree" plots on appropriate number of clusters (you should look
# for a bend in the graph)
nc <- NbClust(df, min.nc=2, max.nc=20, method="kmeans") 
table(nc$Best.n[1,]) 

# creating a bar chart to visualize results on appropriate number
# of clusters
barplot(table(nc$Best.n[1,]), 
      xlab="Number of Clusters", ylab="Number of Criteria",
      main="Number of Clusters Chosen by Criteria")
```

If you still run into problems even after specifying the number of clusters 
suggested by the functions in the `NbClust` package, then another problem
could be with your removal of sparse terms. Try adjusting the "sparse"
option downward and then examine the output from the k-means clustering.

Comment: Hi, can I now what do you mean by "adjusting the "sparse" option downward"? I noticed after I removeSparseTerms and transposed the matrix, my dataset contained only 2 column which are "booking" and "flight". Not sure why?